# AdMob interstitial shown only once on iOS

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

I'm using admob interstitial on my iOS app.
I'm able to display the interstitial only one time, any further request to display a new interstitial fails (delegate is never called by the way).

My code is as follow:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self allocateAndDisplayAd];
}

-(void) allocateAndDisplayAd
{
  splashInterstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
  splashInterstitial_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-MY-ID";
  splashInterstitial_.delegate = self;

  GADRequest *requestInterstitial = [GADRequest request];
  [splashInterstitial_ loadRequest: requestInterstitial];
}

// below functions delegate are never triggered when requesting a new interstitial !!
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad
{
    [splashInterstitial_ presentFromRootViewController: self];
}

- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)ad didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
  splashInterstitial_ = nil;
}

- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad
{
  splashInterstitial_ = nil;
}
```

The interstitial is properly displayed when app launches (request done from the viewDidLoad), then any new request (call to allocateAndDisplayAd) fails (no error message, delegate function never called).

I tried to set splashInterstitial_ = nil; so I'm sure the next request will reallocate a new interstitial, but no way to display more than one ad.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: First: make sure that `splashInterstitial_` must be dealloc after it was used (you can overwrite `GADInterstitial` class to be sure). Second: where did you declare `splashInterstitial_`?

Comment: Hi
I'm using arc in Xcode is I cannot use the release function.
splashInterstitial_ = nil; is supposed to dealloc the object.
The object splashInterstitial_ is declared in the .h of my view controller.

Thanks for your answer 
Jerome

Comment: Did you receive any error?

Comment: No, as mentioned in my original post, the delegate functions are not called anymore.

Comment: When and how did you call to `allocateAndDisplayAd`?

Comment: allocateAndDisplayAd is called from two difference sources:

- When the app launches the viewDidLoad is called then  allocateAndDisplayAd is called (see my code above).

>> This first call works fine.

Then, when the app was in the background then enters in the foreground, if 5 min have passed from the last time the app entered into the background, then the appDelegate calls allocateAndDisplayAd

>> allocateAndDisplayAd is properly called, but nothing happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56087/discussion-between-viethung-and-jerome).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my issue

Any request to show interstitial from applicationWillEnterForeground will be ignored ...
And my second request was done from applicationWillEnterForeground